# How do you configure Confidant to use the Access Key Id/Secret Access Key for its IAM user?

Tags: amazon-iam

I've read through the documentation a couple of times now and it's really clear about how to set up an IAM user for Confidant and what permissions to assign to it. But I can't seem to figure out how to get Confidant the credentials for the user I created. Could y'all please point me in the right direction?

Note: I've also asked this question on [Confidant's google forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/confidant-users/Tw5dbNwFIJU). If I get an answer there I'll be sure to post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ryan Lane, the maintainer of Confidant, got back to me on their google forum. Here is what he had to say:

> In general we try not to use IAM users. We always use IAM roles when
>   possible, which makes the IAM credentials automatically available to
>   confidant via the metadata service on an EC2 instance.
>
> That said, confidant uses boto3/botocore for all AWS actions, so any
>   way in which you can configure boto3 for IAM access will work:
>   http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html. The
>   easiest method is to export the necessary environment variables before
>   you start confidant, since confidant uses environment variables for
>   the rest of its settings:
>   http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html#environment-variables